# Using footable in Ruby on Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, footable

How do I include footable in Ruby on Rails 4?
In my Gemfile I added `gem 'foo_table-rails'` 
I did a `bundle install` after that.

In my application.js I wrote: `//= require footable.core`
In application.scss I wrote: `//= require footable.core`

I have tried even `*= require footable-rails` , but unfortunately it is not working.

My application.scss is as shown below:

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
*= require footable.metro
```

PS: I have already installed bootstrap & I have been using its templates.

Answer (score 0):

Your application.js is correct, but in your application.scss, you need to choose a theme, if you're starting with the metro theme for example use:

```
*= require footable.metro
```

Try changing your application.scss to:

```
/*  
*= require footable.metro
*= require_self
*/
@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";
```

Comment: I get an error?: Invalid CSS after "... footable.metro": expected "{", was ""

Comment: Can you post your application.css contents?

Comment: Updated in the question

Comment: Yea this works, however do I need to add any other file for getting the icon for toggle-circle-filled? I have my table inside a div <div class="container table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped toggle-circle-filled">, but when i view in mobile view the expand icon isnt present

Comment: I actually put footable.css in my assets/stylesheets folder after which your command worked. Am I doing it wrong?

Comment: Where did you get footable.css?  You shouldn't have to do that.   If your gem is installed correctly, it should be in your bundler assets.

Comment: I took it from their website! My gem installed successfully!